# PHP exec() and system() functions always return false in IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, system, exec

I'm trying to use the PHP exec() or system() (or any other similar function) to run a batch file, but I can't seem to get these to return anything.

The simplest example I've seen is this, which outputs nothing:

```
<?php
    echo system('dir');
?>
```

The script is running on a windows XP machine on IIS with PHP installed and I've also tried it on my shared hosting account running windows 2003 server/IIS.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get this working, or provide any commands I can use for troubleshooting?

Cheers,

Tom

**Edit: second example**

Based on pavun_cool's answer I tried the following:

```
<?php
    $last_line = system('dir', $retval);
    echo 'last_line '.$last_line.'<br/> retval '.$retval;
?>
```

The output is:

```
last_line
retval -1
```

**Edit: third example**

Based on Manos Dilaverakis I tried the following code

```
<?php
exec('dir', $response);
foreach($response as $line) {
    echo $line . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
<br>
```

I.e. a blank line when displayed in a browser.

Also looking in `php.ini`, the following line (which presumably could disable these functions) is empty:

```
disable_functions =
```

Does anyone have any further suggestions or anything else I can try?

Comment: ...PHP's manual pages on exec and system answer this. You don't even need to scroll down

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis - could you be a bit more specific? The text from the exec function states "Return Values: The last line from the result of the command." - so shouldn't I see the last line of output from whatever I run run?

Answer (score 1):

For getting return values , you need to pass the second argument for system function .

```
$last_line = system('ls', $retval);
```

Here `$retval` will have the return value of the ls execution.

Comment: I tried this and added it to my question above - $retval is -1 rather than the output I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

When working with windows and PHP, several commands (including `dir`, and other windows commands such as ping) do not output their return values properly to the `php.exe` binary.  For example, trying to get `dir` to produce output with a PHP `shell_exec()` function will always result in "false".  If you attempt to give it a value like `dir c:\` it will result in:  `NULL` which is similar to `FALSE` in that it provides nothing useful.  The ONLY workaround is to use php's built in `scandir()` and make your own version of `dir` manually with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here, if this doesn't work, then exec's probably disabled in php.ini, which means you'll have to change your PHP configuration

```
<?php
exec('dir', $response);
foreach($response as $line) {
    echo $line . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've just tried this, and the output is simply <br> also there don't appear to be any functions disabled in php.ini.